# Models from my Alembic files (.abc) have flattened node hierarchies and are missing faces in iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, houdini, alembic-format

I'm trying to export a simple 3D scene from Houdini and use it in an iOS app (with SceneKit). But I'm encountering many troubles after I add the .abc file to my XCode project. My two main problems are:

Firstly, Scene Graph doesn't seem to detect child nodes in my .abc files. Instead, iOS/XCode appears to flatten all my nested subnetworks/child nodes into top-level nodes, none of which show their children. How can I preserve my node hierarchy? Do I need to make changes in my Houdini network to explicitly mark nodes as children?

Secondly, my models lose their color data and look broken. If I convert .abc to .scn, they look a little better, but they still look broken. Am I missing a step here? Do I need to manually add materials or do something different with lighting? Why does my scene look nothing like is does rendered in Houdini?

This is how it's supposed to look:
[image]

This is how it looks in iOS:
[image]

This is how it looks after conversion to .scn. Slightly better but still broken.
[image]

Comment: Did you add proper lighting?
If you pause at runtime, how does it look when using debug view hierarchy and selecting the scene or subelements?